# How do I access timeoutID in callback

Tags: callback, purescript

I want to write like this with [`purescript-timers`](https://github.com/legokichi/purescript-timers/blob/issue%237/docs/Control/Timer.md).

```
main = do
  t <- interval 10 $ do
    clearInterval t
```

Error occur

> Unknown value t

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with this code? As  PureScript has strict semantics you cannot use the result of a function as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Ref`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-refs/4.1.0/docs/Effect.Ref#t:Ref) to store and read the ID.

```
main = do
  idRef ← Ref.new (-1)
  id ← interval 10 (Ref.read idRef >>= clearInterval)
  Ref.write id idRef
```

The reason your program does not compile is because `t` is only in scope *after* the binder. In other words, any statements afterwards in the do-block can use `t` but no statements before can, nor can the statement itself use `t`.

In this solution with `Ref`, because `idRef` is bound in a statement beforehand, it can be used anywhere in the statements following.